# Odd primes more than a certain number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am tasked to write a simple logical statement on this statement "All primes $n$, $n$ greater or equals to $3$, are odd.".

For a start, I have

$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ (n \geq 3 ...)$

I apologise for the formatting, quite new though I followed the MathJax guide.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall p\in P: p \ge 3 \Rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb N \; \& \; p=2n+1$, where $P$ denotes the set of all primes.

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall n > 2 \wedge n \in \mathbb{P}, \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ {\rm s.t.}\  n = 2k + 1$$

Where ${\rm s.t.}$ is read "such that."